# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression error

Tags: oracle

I have made a database name enquiry which has got the details the code is showing the error misssing expression.

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String d=jTextField1.getText();
         String e=jTextField2.getText();
          try
        {
            connect ob=new connect();
            Connection con=ob.conn();
            PreparedStatement pr=con.prepareStatement("select * from ENQUIRY where from=? and to=?");

            pr.setString(1,d);
            pr.setString(2,e);
            ResultSet rs=pr.executeQuery();
            boolean status=false;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                status=true;
            }
            if(status==true)
            {
                new NewJFrame13().setVisible(true);
            }
            else
            {
                    new NewJFrame5().setVisible(true);

            }

        super.dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception a)
        {
            System.out.println(a);      
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the table structure of `Enquiry`?

Answer (score 0):

Using column names of from/to is probably not a good idea, as those are reserved words in oracle.  You need to change the query to:

```
select * from ENQUIRY where "from"=? and "to"=?
```